# Change Text in iframes with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I've made a great chrome extension that redacts words I don't like...except i can't get it to work in iframes...I already have in my manifest:

```
   "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
   "all_frames": true,
    "run_at" : "document_idle",
  "js": ["jquery-1.11.0.min.js", "myscript.js"],
```

my code is simple:

```
$('body :not(:has(*))').text(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/OFFENDING-WORD/ig, '▓▓▓▓▓▓');    
});
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Due to [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), you cannot access the contents of iframes not on the same domain. They are completely opaque (i.e. javascript cannot even see the contents) to all scripts running on the page, or extensions. There's nothing you can do. Unless the source of the iframe is the exact same domain (which would be rare) or the source page has a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set (also rare), then no code running in any browser will ever be able to access any content of that iframe. While it's annoying at times, it's an incredibly important security feature that prevents all sorts of malicious activity.

Edit: Sorry, I was originally writing CORS when I meant Same-Origin Policy. CORS is the method to get around SOP around execute code, but it requires Access-Control-Allow-Origin to be set.

Comment: I understand completely Cross Origin Resource Sharing and it's importance. However, I'm looking to change text at the browser level...is there perhaps a chrome browser API that can achieve the same result? I'm only using javascript because of it's simplicity.

Comment: That's what I'm saying though. Unless the source of the iframe is the exact same domain (which would be rare) or the source page has a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set (also rare), then no code running in any browser will _ever_ be able to access any content of that iframe. You're out of luck unless you write your own browser which somehow ignores CORS.

Comment: -1 Because the answer **incorrectly** suggests that replacing text inside iframes is not possible in a Chrome extension. There are some ways for Chrome extensions to run code in a different frame.

Comment: Sorry @RobW, but you're wrong, unless, as I already mentioned, the iframe is from the same origin or A-C-A-O is set. The original question was obviously looking for a way to replace text in *all* iframes which just isn't possible.

Comment: @Mordred Normal web pages cannot access content from other origins, but **Chrome extensions** *can*. The way to do that is stated in the question (`"all_frames": true`). (The reason for failing has nothing to do with iframes, but with the fact that jQuery can only select elements, not text nodes. So elements text nodes with `<br>`s would not be matched.)

Comment: @RobW My apologies then. I knew about `all_frames` but apparently I had a misunderstanding of how it worked.